# How do I turn a h2 Markdown header into a link?

Tags: github, markdown, jekyll, github-pages, github-flavored-markdown

I'm new to creating sites with Jekyll and markdown in general, so please tell me if there is something obviously wrong with my approach.

My code is:

```
[## Red Hat Certified Systems Administrator (RHCSA) Guide]({% post_url 2017-09-11-RHCSA %})
```

The output I was expecting was an h2 Header that's also a link. 
However, when I serve the page using Jekyll, the link works perfectly, but instead of the link text being a h2 header, it simply contains `## Red Hat Certified Systems Administrator (RHCSA) Guide`.

So, how do I nest the `<h2>` tag inside the `<a href>` tag using markdown?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Okay, guys... turns out I've been monumentally stupid. While I'm still confused why the markdown won't accept a header tag inside the link, there's a simple workaround!

Simply put the `##` tag outside the link's brackets. Thus, the proper code (that works) is:

```
## [Red Hat Certified Systems Administrator (RHCSA) Guide]({% post_url 2017-09-11-RHCSA %})
```

So, a link to Google.co.in would become:

```
## [Google](https://google.co.in)
```

> **Output** :
>
> ### [Google](https://google.co.in)

Thanks to all that viewed the question and tried to help.

I leave this here in hopes that one day some unfortunate soul lands here in the same predicament as I did and finds this.

Comment: The reason is that Markdown works in a hierarchy of block-level and inline markup. The header is a block-level element while the link is an inline element. A block-level element is made up of inline elements (and plain text). However, an inline element cannot contain block-level elements. For more details, see the [Blocks and inlines section](https://github.github.com/gfm/#blocks-and-inlines) of the Spec.